# How to order the bars ggplot2 facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I dont know how to order the bars from the highest bar to the lowest.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqHny.png) Please someone whow could be help me.

This a head of my data frame

```
 head(datos)
    # A tibble: 6 x 3
      Entidad                 Cantidad Periodo         
      <fct>                      <dbl> <fct>           
    1 Ministerios                   22 4/12/18-27/03/19
    2 Gobierno                      19 4/12/18-27/03/19
    3 Instituciones Autónomas       13 4/12/18-27/03/19
    4 Poder Judicial                 3 4/12/18-27/03/19
    5 Poder Legislativo              2 4/12/18-27/03/19
    6 Presidencia                    1 4/12/18-27/03/19
```

This is my code

```
datos$Periodo <- factor(datos$Periodo,
                            levels = c(1,2),
                            labels = c("4/12/18-27/03/19", "28/03/19-30/09/19"))

    datos$Entidad <- factor(datos$Entidad, 
                       levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13),
                       labels = c("Ministerios","Gobierno","Instituciones Autónomas","Poder Judicial","Poder Legislativo","Presidencia","Individuos","Otros","Ministerios","Poder Legislativo","Gobierno","Instituciones Autónomas","Menos de 10"))


    #Grafico final: Grafico de barras h. agrupadas

    ggplot(datos, aes(Entidad, Cantidad, group = Periodo)) +
      geom_bar(aes(fill= Periodo), stat = "identity", position='dodge') +
      ggtitle("Tipo de Entidad", subtitle = "Periodo: Diciembre 2018 - Septiembre 2019") +
      # se eliminan los titulos de los ejes
      theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
      #Se colocan los seis graficos en una sola pantalla
      facet_wrap(~Periodo, scale = "free") +
      #Se rotan las etiquetas del eje x
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8))
```

Comment: Any time `ggplot2` and "how to order" comes into play, I think `factor`. Set up your facet variable as a `factor` where you control the order with `factor(Periodo, levels=...)` and things should just work.

Comment: Said differently ... you are (obviously) using factors and levels, but ... you are defining your levels from lowest to highest. So define it from highest to lowest instead. (Perhaps `factor(datos$Periodo, levels=c(2,1), labels=c("28/03/19-30/09/19","4/12/18-27/03/19"))`.)

Comment: I think you dont understand me. What i want is to order the facet variable. I need to organize both of the facet varaible since the bar with the highest value to the bar with the lowest value. I dont want to change the order of the facet variable i want to change the order of the bars of both facet varaibles

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry I misread it. But still, it's still `factor`, I know if no way to order it without externally setting `factor(..., levels=...)`.

Comment: I already used factor in the script. But when i use factor only organized the first facet varaible, and not the second one. I want to order both of them

Comment: `datos$Entidad <- factor(datos$Entidad, levels=datos$Entidad[ order(-datos$Cantidad) ])` ordered the bars from most to least (with this sample data).

Comment: When i run your code this error appears: Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [4] is duplicated

Comment: Sounds like you need to `unique` the levels before ordering them and assigning the factor.